Any local system on a curve is trivial?
Given a local system $L$ of rank $1$ on a smooth projective curve $C$, which is given by $\pi_1(C)\to \mathbf{C}^*$. Consider $L'=L\otimes O_C$. The line bundle $L'$ is trivial on an open subset $C^0$ of $C$. Hence the restriction of $L$ on $C^0$ is tirivial. Hence by $\pi_1(C^0)\to\pi_1(C)\to\mathbf{C}^*$ and $\pi_1(C^0)\to\pi_1(C)$ is surjective, $\pi_1(C)\to\mathbf{C}^*$ is trivial. Thus we get that $L$ is a trivial local system ?
This can't be true, but I don's know what's wrong with my argument?

Why would the map of fundamental groups be surjective? Without further assumptions on $C^0$ it could be a contractible open subset, for instance.

This is my argument. By Seifert–Van Kampen theorem, $\pi_1(C)$ is the quotient of $\pi_1(C^0)$ by  subgroup generated by loops around points in $C\setminus C^0$.
